# Tabelas com scroll vertical e horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, tabela-html, rolamento

Montei uma tabela com *scroll* horizontal e vertical a partir deste original http://jsfiddle.net/k5k7vtwu/:

```js
document.querySelector('.ux-data-table').onscroll = function (e) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
  var topOfDiv = Math.max(document.querySelector(".ux-data-table").scrollTop - 2, 0);
  document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0].style = "top:" + topOfDiv + "px;";
}
```

```css
.ux-data-table {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  float:left;
}
.ux-data-table1 {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  float:left;
}

/* Prevents the header from overflowing the scrollbars */
.ux-data-table-inner {
  position: relative;
}
.ux-data-table-inner1 {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table table {
  width: 100%;
}
.ux-data-table1 table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ux-data-table table,
.ux-data-table th,
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
.ux-data-table1 table,
.ux-data-table1 th,
.ux-data-table1 td {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.ux-data-table thead {
  position: absolute;
}
.ux-data-table1 thead {
  position: absolute;
}

.ux-data-table tbody {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
.ux-data-table1 tbody {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.ux-data-table1 td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h4>
 Tabela 1
</h4>
<div class='ux-data-table'>
  <div class='ux-data-table-inner'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
<th>COLOCAÇÃO</th>
<th>Nº</th>
<th>NOME</th>
<th>CÓD. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>COL. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>TEMPO SWIM</th>
<th>T1</th>
<th>TEMPO BIKE</th>
<th>T2</th>
<th>TEMPO RUN</th>
<th>TEMPO TOTAL</th>
<th>EQUIPE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>MARCUS VINICIUS FERNANDES</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:11:32</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:45:36</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:22:01</td>
<td>01:20:07</td>
<td>MF ASSESSORIA ESPORTIVA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>FELIPE JOSÉ MOLETTA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:37</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:44:34</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:21:29</td>
<td>01:20:27</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>FERNANDO LUNARDELLI TOLDI</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:12:20</td>
<td>00:00:18</td>
<td>00:47:46</td>
<td>00:00:17</td>
<td>00:21:58</td>
<td>01:22:39</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>RAFAEL GOMES JURITI FERREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:15</td>
<td>00:45:58</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:24:54</td>
<td>01:26:28</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>RAUL FURTADO</td>
<td>M4044</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:34</td>
<td>00:00:27</td>
<td>00:46:59</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:25:08</td>
<td>01:26:38</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>HUGO AMARAL HORTA BARBOSA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:26</td>
<td>00:00:40</td>
<td>00:48:38</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:25:01</td>
<td>01:28:11</td>
<td>FIBRATECH</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>JUSCELINO ADEODATO DE MIRANDA VASCO</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:40</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:50:36</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:25:41</td>
<td>01:31:44</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>GUSTAVO SLAIB CRUZ PEREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:51:53</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:26:03</td>
<td>01:33:46</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>PETER PICHNOFF</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:19</td>
<td>00:53:30</td>
<td>00:00:43</td>
<td>00:26:30</td>
<td>01:35:57</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<h4>
 Tabela 2
</h4>
<div class='ux-data-table1'>
  <div class='ux-data-table-inner1'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
<th>COLOCAÇÃO</th>
<th>Nº</th>
<th>NOME</th>
<th>CÓD. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>COL. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>TEMPO SWIM</th>
<th>T1</th>
<th>TEMPO BIKE</th>
<th>T2</th>
<th>TEMPO RUN</th>
<th>TEMPO TOTAL</th>
<th>EQUIPE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>MARCUS VINICIUS FERNANDES</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:11:32</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:45:36</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:22:01</td>
<td>01:20:07</td>
<td>MF ASSESSORIA ESPORTIVA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>FELIPE JOSÉ MOLETTA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:37</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:44:34</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:21:29</td>
<td>01:20:27</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>FERNANDO LUNARDELLI TOLDI</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:12:20</td>
<td>00:00:18</td>
<td>00:47:46</td>
<td>00:00:17</td>
<td>00:21:58</td>
<td>01:22:39</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>RAFAEL GOMES JURITI FERREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:15</td>
<td>00:45:58</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:24:54</td>
<td>01:26:28</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>RAUL FURTADO</td>
<td>M4044</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:34</td>
<td>00:00:27</td>
<td>00:46:59</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:25:08</td>
<td>01:26:38</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>HUGO AMARAL HORTA BARBOSA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:26</td>
<td>00:00:40</td>
<td>00:48:38</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:25:01</td>
<td>01:28:11</td>
<td>FIBRATECH</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>JUSCELINO ADEODATO DE MIRANDA VASCO</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:40</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:50:36</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:25:41</td>
<td>01:31:44</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>GUSTAVO SLAIB CRUZ PEREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:51:53</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:26:03</td>
<td>01:33:46</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>PETER PICHNOFF</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:19</td>
<td>00:53:30</td>
<td>00:00:43</td>
<td>00:26:30</td>
<td>01:35:57</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como eu preciso de vária tabelas diferentes numa mesma página, dupliquei a tabela original, alterei os estilos CSS e o JS que está sendo usado, alterando as IDs e classes, mas mesmo assim o topo das tabelas (thead) não ficam fixas na rolagem vertical como está na primeira (Tabela 1).

Achei que duplicando a função e alterando as classes e IDs fosse funcionar, mas não rolou.

Alguém poderia me indicar o que preciso corrigir para que o *scroll* das tabelas funcionem de forma igual?

Comment: Cara vc usa esse JS só para deixar essa thead fixa? Da para deixar ela parada sem precisar de JS, vai funcionar o Chrome, Firefox, Edge e Safari. Se te interessar posso fazer um modelo

Comment: @hugocsl Fiz uma solução seguindo a linha de raciocínio dele. Mas não ousei a fazer apenas com CSS. Essa é por sua conta! ;D

Comment: caro @LipESprY e hugocsl, muito obrigado pelas respostas! Acabei usando esse exemplo com JS porque quando testei travar o header da tabela só com CSS,  zoava ao scroll horizontal.

Comment: O JS pode até funcionar. Mas o CSS, no final, acaba sendo uma solução mais limpa! #off não subestime nosso amigo @hugocsl que "brinca" com css!

Comment: @LipESprY haha vou postar a resposta só com CSS sem buggar nenhum scroll!

Comment: @hugocsl, com certeza um expert em CSS tiraria isso de letra. Não é meu caso, rs apesar de conseguir me virar bem. Usando o JS pode me prejudicar em termos de compatibilidade de navegadores ou mesmo na responsividade?

Comment: Ainda não tive problema de compatibilidade com códigos JavaScript. Único problema que já tive foi com Internet Explorer. Mas ele nem conta como navegador. kkk. Sobre responsividade: vai além do JavaScript. O básico se faz via estilização. ;D

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha para ela ficar responsiva basta colocar o width da div e da tabela da minha resposta em %

Comment: show @hugocsl, vou trabalhar na responsividade dela!!! Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

Segue um modelo só com CSS, testei no FireFox, Chrome e Edge, mas muito provavelmente tb vai funcionar no Safari.

A ideia é simples, basicamente basta colocar `position: sticky;` no `th`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
table {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #babaca;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px green; 
}
td {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px green;  
}
div {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Coluna 1</td>
          <td>Coluna 2</td>
          <td>Coluna 3</td>
          <td>Coluna 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: A solução foi top! Mas é uma pena que o `sticky` não tenha uma boa [compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). =X

Comment: Fantástico @hugocsl ! Sem palavras pra agradecer. Tinha trocado de fixed para sticky e nao tinha funcionado. Só não precisava ter usado a cor #babaca hehehehe, mas vou entender como uma zoeirinha!

Comment: `#babaca` kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha  na verdade que eu vejo muito a cor #BADA55 badass nos códigos por ai, ai eu deu una aportuguesada haha, nada pessoal. Sobre o position fixed ele eh em relação a pagina como um todo, com fixed realmente não daria certo

Comment: @LipESprY easter egg da zueira RSS, esse era um código que já tinha aqui Pq uso de vez em quando e não lembrava que tinha usado essa cor, apesar que esse tipo de brincadeira nas cores eh comum até na gringa

Comment: @hugocsl, na versão responsiva, testando pelo celular e nao pelo inspetor do browser, o topo não fica fixo. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha e o que vc fez nessa versão mobile? Tem como vc colocar seu código no codepen ou algo assim? Esse exato modelo da minha resposta eu acabei de testar aqui no meu celular Android e funcionou

Comment: @hugocsl, tava tentando editar a resposta. No Android realmente rolou, apenas no Chrome no iPhone que o topo da tabela sobe junto no hover :(

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha por isso falei que ela podi não ser tão crosbrowser quanto opções com JS, mas teste colocando o vendor prefix do Safari, dessa forma onde tiver a propriedade, ai vc deixa o que já está lá e coloca tb `-webkit-position: sticky;` e assim tb `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com o -webk, @hugocsl it!! Valeu, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha que bom que deu certo ai! Se vc acredita que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone `✔`. Assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta não resolvida. Vc pode remover esse voto a qualquer momento caso queira, ou coloca-lo em outra resposta que surja e vc ache que te atende melhor. []´s

Comment: @hugocsl, eu votei, mas como sou novo aqui no stack (reputação com menos de 15), meu voto não é computado :(.

Comment: @ManoelVilhenaSaldanha a entendi, nem lembrava mais que tinha isso rss, achei que para aceitar uma resposta não precisa de reputação mínima... O ícone para aceitar é esse ícone `✔` ele fica logo abaixo das Setinhas, na verdade não precisa clicar na setinha para poder aceitar uma resposta. Basta clicar no ✅ abaixo das setas das postas na resposta que vc escolher, pois só pode marcar uma resposta como aceita...

Answer (score 1):

O principal objetivo das classes no CSS é reaproveitar a estilização. Você acabou andando para trás duplicando todos os estilos e mudando só o nome. Nessa situação era melhor você adicionar um ID e alterar o seletor do JavaScript para os IDs criados.

Melhor ainda é você não utilizar IDs. Apenas criar um seletor que encontra o `thead` da tabela que está sendo rolada.

Lógico que você pode fazer isso SEM JavaScript! Seria uma solução muito mais limpa. O que você está fazendo é "fixar o `thead` quando rola a tabela". Mas o que te impede de já deixar ele fixo ali logo ao carregar o documento, direto na estilização?

Voltando à proposta da pergunta, apaguei as duplicatas da estilização, padronizei os estilos na segunda tabela e refiz o JavaScript com a teoria que passei acima.

Veja como ficou:

```js
for (let tab of document.querySelectorAll('.ux-data-table')) {
  tab.onscroll = function (e) {
    var topOfDiv = Math.max(e.target.scrollTop - 2, 0);
    e.target.querySelector('div > table > thead').style.top = topOfDiv+'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.ux-data-table {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  float:left;
}

/* Prevents the header from overflowing the scrollbars */
.ux-data-table-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ux-data-table table,
.ux-data-table th,
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.ux-data-table thead {
  position: absolute;
}

.ux-data-table tbody {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h4>
 Tabela 1
</h4>
<div class='ux-data-table'>
  <div class='ux-data-table-inner'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
<th>COLOCAÇÃO</th>
<th>Nº</th>
<th>NOME</th>
<th>CÓD. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>COL. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>TEMPO SWIM</th>
<th>T1</th>
<th>TEMPO BIKE</th>
<th>T2</th>
<th>TEMPO RUN</th>
<th>TEMPO TOTAL</th>
<th>EQUIPE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>MARCUS VINICIUS FERNANDES</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:11:32</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:45:36</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:22:01</td>
<td>01:20:07</td>
<td>MF ASSESSORIA ESPORTIVA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>FELIPE JOSÉ MOLETTA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:37</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:44:34</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:21:29</td>
<td>01:20:27</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>FERNANDO LUNARDELLI TOLDI</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:12:20</td>
<td>00:00:18</td>
<td>00:47:46</td>
<td>00:00:17</td>
<td>00:21:58</td>
<td>01:22:39</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>RAFAEL GOMES JURITI FERREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:15</td>
<td>00:45:58</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:24:54</td>
<td>01:26:28</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>RAUL FURTADO</td>
<td>M4044</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:34</td>
<td>00:00:27</td>
<td>00:46:59</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:25:08</td>
<td>01:26:38</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>HUGO AMARAL HORTA BARBOSA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:26</td>
<td>00:00:40</td>
<td>00:48:38</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:25:01</td>
<td>01:28:11</td>
<td>FIBRATECH</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>JUSCELINO ADEODATO DE MIRANDA VASCO</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:40</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:50:36</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:25:41</td>
<td>01:31:44</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>GUSTAVO SLAIB CRUZ PEREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:51:53</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:26:03</td>
<td>01:33:46</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>PETER PICHNOFF</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:19</td>
<td>00:53:30</td>
<td>00:00:43</td>
<td>00:26:30</td>
<td>01:35:57</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<h4>
 Tabela 2
</h4>
<div class='ux-data-table'>
  <div class='ux-data-table-inner'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
<th>COLOCAÇÃO</th>
<th>Nº</th>
<th>NOME</th>
<th>CÓD. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>COL. FAIXA ETÁRIA</th>
<th>TEMPO SWIM</th>
<th>T1</th>
<th>TEMPO BIKE</th>
<th>T2</th>
<th>TEMPO RUN</th>
<th>TEMPO TOTAL</th>
<th>EQUIPE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>MARCUS VINICIUS FERNANDES</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:11:32</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:45:36</td>
<td>00:00:29</td>
<td>00:22:01</td>
<td>01:20:07</td>
<td>MF ASSESSORIA ESPORTIVA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>FELIPE JOSÉ MOLETTA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:37</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:44:34</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:21:29</td>
<td>01:20:27</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>FERNANDO LUNARDELLI TOLDI</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:12:20</td>
<td>00:00:18</td>
<td>00:47:46</td>
<td>00:00:17</td>
<td>00:21:58</td>
<td>01:22:39</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>RAFAEL GOMES JURITI FERREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:15</td>
<td>00:45:58</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:24:54</td>
<td>01:26:28</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>RAUL FURTADO</td>
<td>M4044</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:34</td>
<td>00:00:27</td>
<td>00:46:59</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:25:08</td>
<td>01:26:38</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>HUGO AMARAL HORTA BARBOSA</td>
<td>M3034</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:13:26</td>
<td>00:00:40</td>
<td>00:48:38</td>
<td>00:00:26</td>
<td>00:25:01</td>
<td>01:28:11</td>
<td>FIBRATECH</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>JUSCELINO ADEODATO DE MIRANDA VASCO</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:40</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:50:36</td>
<td>00:00:22</td>
<td>00:25:41</td>
<td>01:31:44</td>
<td>(nenhuma)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>GUSTAVO SLAIB CRUZ PEREIRA</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:25</td>
<td>00:51:53</td>
<td>00:00:30</td>
<td>00:26:03</td>
<td>01:33:46</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>PETER PICHNOFF</td>
<td>M3539</td>
<td>–</td>
<td>00:14:55</td>
<td>00:00:19</td>
<td>00:53:30</td>
<td>00:00:43</td>
<td>00:26:30</td>
<td>01:35:57</td>
<td>GP COACHING</td>
</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Seguindo esse código, você pode adicionar quantas tabelas quiser. Basta manter a mesma classe! O JavaScript vai permanecer o mesmo para todas as tabelas!

Fiz essas alterações seguindo o exemplo original (postado na pergunta) e apliquei no seu. Por fim, deixei disponível no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2a3n4fs/).

Comment: Muito boa a explicação, talvez seja uma solução mais crossbrowser que apenas com CSS